# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + n^2}$ is an uniform convergent series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was required to prove  that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + n^2}$  is an uniform convergent series.

**My attempt :** $ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + n^2}$

Now $\frac{1}{x^2 + n^2} \leq \frac{1}{ n^2}$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Now  we know $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^2}$  is convergent. So  for every $\epsilon > 0$ , we will get a natural number $K$ such that $ \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^2} < \epsilon$ .

Thus ,  for every  $\epsilon > 0$ , we will get a natural number $K$ such that  $ \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + n^2} < \epsilon$  for all $x \in \mathbb R$.
Therefore , $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + n^2}$ is an uniform convergent series.

Can anyone please check my attempt? Have I gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. However, I would use the M-test theorem for simplicity.

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + n^2}$, It is clear that

$f_n(x) \leq M_n =\frac{1}{ n^2}$  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} M_n$ is convergent ,($\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} M_n =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$), then the M-test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) asserts that the series $\sum_0^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 +n^2}$  is uniformly convergent.